# What ORB algorithm implementations are available?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

We want implement ORB algorithm on C# language. Yes, we can use OpenCV with wrapping, but it's very heavy for our purposes.

I make some research in web and found only this https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp and try to reimplement ORB source.

But now it's works with multiple bugs and very slow, I think we make some mistakes.

OpenCV have a lot of macros and links to other functions from OCV Core. And C++ it's very hard for sugar-language programmers like C#.

Would you get some links on other ORB implementations (may be on other languages), or good theoretical link, where we can check our C# ORB implementation step by step?

Comment: @sgarizvi We wan't use ORB on xamarin.iOS/xamarin.Android/UWP. For this purposes cost: Price: $ 399 USD for a single developer. It's cool, but expensive only for ORB keypoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other implementations I found:

- [`skimage.feature.ORB`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#orb) (Python) with source code in master [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/orb.py#L22)
- [Arrayfire ORB](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/blob/v3.4.2/src/backend/cpu/orb.cpp)

Comment: great, python source more readable for me and this cpp code have less macros expressions!

Answer (score 2):

There is a good post about explanation of ORB descriptor: [A tutorial on binary descriptors – part 3 – The ORB descriptor](https://gilscvblog.com/2013/10/04/a-tutorial-on-binary-descriptors-part-3-the-orb-descriptor/). If you want to know detailed information leave a comment to this post.

Also try to read the original paper [ORB: an efficient alternative to SIFT or SURF](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf).

You may contact to the authors about source code via emails directly.